# SPDLOG_LOGGER_CALL and __VA_ARGS__ in

Tags: c++, variadic-functions, variadic-macros, spdlog

I'm trying to understand why my variadic arguments don't work in `spdlog`. I understand that there is an `SPDLOG_LOGGER_INFO` macro to do what I do, but at the moment I need to understand how `SPDLOG_LOGGER_CALL` works. So here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <spdlog/sinks/syslog_sink.h>
#include <spdlog/spdlog.h>
#include <memory>
#include <syslog.h>

int main()
{
    auto logger = std::make_shared<spdlog::logger>(
            "logger", 
            std::make_shared<spdlog::sinks::syslog_sink_mt>(
                "", LOG_ODELAY, LOG_USER, true));
    std::string msg = "my message";
    int i = 10;
    SPDLOG_LOGGER_CALL(logger, spdlog::level::info, "%d %s", i, msg);
    return 0;
}
```

After I compile it I get the following output

```
Aug 12 9:38:03 mymachine test: [2021-08-12 9:38:03.424] [logger] [info] [main.cpp:30] %d %s
```

However I'm expecting to see a full message in the output, i.e.

```
Aug 12 9:38:03 mymachine test: [2021-08-12 9:38:03.424] [logger] [info] [main.cpp:30] 10 my message
```

I feel like I'm missing something small but important. Would someone care to help out?

[Here is where SPDLOG_LOGGER_CALL defined](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/blob/v1.9.1/include/spdlog/spdlog.h#L291)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SPDLOG_LOGGER_CALL()` is just a wrapper for `spdlog::logger::log()`, which does not use `printf`-style format strings, like you are expecting.  If you read [spdlog's documentation](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog), you will see that spdlog uses the [{fmt}](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) library internally:

> Feature rich formatting, using the excellent [fmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) library.

Which has its [own syntax for format strings](https://fmt.dev/latest/syntax.html):

> Format strings contain “replacement fields” surrounded by curly braces `{}`. Anything that is not contained in braces is considered literal text, which is copied unchanged to the output.

That is why you are seeing `%d %s` in your output, as it is being treated as literal text.

Indeed, `spdlog::logger::log()` [ends up calling](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/blob/v1.9.1/include/spdlog/logger.h#L322) `fmt::detail::vformat_to()`, passing it your format strings and arguments as-is.

So, try using `"{} {}"` instead of `"%d %s"`:

```cpp
SPDLOG_LOGGER_CALL(logger, spdlog::level::info, "{} {}", i, msg);
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
SPDLOG_LOGGER_CALL(logger, spdlog::level::info, "{:d} {:s}", i, msg);
```